# Assignment to a mutable tuple component in python: a bug? a feature?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability, pep

We know that Python tuples are immutable, good. When I attempt to change the reference of a tuple component I get an exception, as expected. What is not expected, is the component gets changed regardless of the exception, whereas I would have thought tuple immutability guarantees that the object won't be mutable.

Is it a bug, feature or a PEP?

```
In [6]: x=([1],)
In [7]: type(x)
Out[7]: tuple
In [8]: x[0]+=[2,3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a73186f99454> in <module>()
----> 1 x[0]+=[2,3]

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment   
In [9]: x
Out[9]: ([1, 2, 3],)
```

Comment: you aren't the first!

Comment: Also note that for a tuple to be hashable, all of it's components must be hashable.  `hash((1,2,3))` works fine.  `hash(([],[],[]))` will raise an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting point.

The reason it behaves like this is that

```
x[0]+=[2,3]
```

translates to

```
x[0] = x[0].__iadd__([2,3])
```

which means it first calls `__iadd__`, which modifies the list in place, and only then attempts to perform the illegal assignment into the tuple.

(Of course, it's easy to workaround (e.g. @luispedro's answer), but I understand your question is not about how to workaround it.)

> Is it a bug, feature or a PEP?

Hard to say.  I tend to vote for "a bug", because of the Principle of Least Astonishment.  One would expect `x[0].extend(y)` to behave like `a=x[0]; a.extend(y)` to behave like `a=x[0]; a+=y` to behave like `x[0]+=y`.

A possible fix (at least for python built-in types) can be to required that `__setitem__(self, k, v)` should translate to no-op in case `self[k] is v`. (and custom classes overriding `__setitem__` should obey).

Comment: Yes, the code is equivalent to x[0] = x[0].__iadd__([2,3]).I still don't see how the initial reference gets changed despite of an exception. How can I see the code for list.__iadd__(self, other)?

Comment: When executing a line like `x[0] = x[0].__iadd__([2,3])` it first evaluates the expression on the righthand side (`__iadd__`), which modifies the list object in place.  There's no undoing to that.  Only then it carries out the `__setitem__` assignment, which raises an error.

Comment: @shx2 Good explanation, but the vote for "bug" is not appropriate IMO. It's just the way it works.

Comment: @ shx2: got it, thanks, that would be the answer if I could vote for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is even simpler:

```
tup = ([],[])
tup[0].append(0)
tup[1].append(1)
print tup
```

prints out

```
([0],[1])
```

Tuple immutability means that the objects that compose the tuple cannot be changed to different objects. It does not mean that you cannot modify their values.

Now, having said that, you found a very interesting (if that's the word) corner case, which basically translates to:

```
x = tup[0]
x += [2,3]
tup[0] = x
```

So, the first two lines work as expected, then you get an exception.

Comment: My point was that despite an exception being thrown the immutable object gets changed. You kind of don't expect that in my example.

Comment: @p3t3 Nto the immutable object gets changed, but one of its (mutable) members. That's a difference.

Comment: Yes, the exception gets thrown when an attempt is made to change the reference within an immutable object, see below.